# Working with .clientX example in JS any idea why you can not check a given argument?

Tags: javascript, html, arguments, coordinates, w3c

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click in the div element below to get the x (horizontal) and y (vertical) coordinates of the mouse pointer, when it is clicked.</p>

<div onmousemove="showCoords(event)"><p id="demo"></p></div>

<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Try to click different places in the div.</p>

<script>
function showCoords(event) {
    var cX = event.clientX;
    var sX = event.screenX;
    var cY = event.clientY;
    var sY = event.screenY;

    var coords1 = "client - X: " + cX + ", Y coords: " + cY;
    var coords2 = "screen - X: " + sX + ", Y coords: " + sY;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords1 + "<br>" + coords2;

    console.log(cX * 0.5);

    if(cX < 0.5 * cX){
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
    }
    /*else if(cX > cX * 0.5 ){
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "yellow";
    }*/
    else{
        document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "black";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello, I have attached the given example I have been working on via W3schools. I can log cX to the screen dividing it by two. However when I then try to use it in an argument it will not work. Has anyone else came across a similar issue or have I made a fatal error in markup? Please let me know. If I find solution will be sure to post here. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what do you think when you say `try to use it in an argument`, but from my assumption you want to change the color on left side of a screen and right side of a screen. This expression will never be true `if(cX < 0.5 * cX){` so text will always stay black. 

Here is a fiddle of your example which uses `clientWidth` and everything works as expected [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kukicvladimir/f70r0csu/1/)

Comment: @KukicVladimir I see `document.body.clientWidth/2` change here. However can you provide more information to why this expression will never be true?

Comment: assuming that `cX > 0` (in this case it is), how can cX be less then cX/2?

Comment: @KukicVladimir I get your point here, my logic here is impaired. I was going to argue that here given is cX < cX/2 is true however it always will be if I take the given value. Hence why `document.body.clientWidth/2` makes more sense and actually works.

Comment: I am glad it works as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cX < 0.5 * cX){
```

This is always `false`, you probably meant `cX < 0.5 *  document.body.clientWidth`.